# Under which circumstances filter can refuse to work in Python?

Tags: python-3.x, list, filter, iterable

I get the following line

```
 db_dir_content = os.listdir(db_path)
 db_states = filter(is_state, db_dir_content)
```

returning empty iterator, while the following

```
 db_dir_content = os.listdir(db_path)
 db_states = [state for state in db_dir_content if is_state(state)]
```

returning non empty an correct list.

`is_state` is following

```
def is_state(name):
    return _STATE_NAME_PATTERN.match(name) is not None
```

How can it be and how to fix?

Comment: what is _STATE_NAME_PATTERN

Comment: it is `_STATE_NAME_PATTERN = re.compile('^\d{8}-\d{6}$')` but I don't think it matters

Comment: Its working fine. filter returns iterator. convert iterator to list using list(db_states).

Comment: @AkashPagar converting to list makes empty list

Comment: what this _STATE_NAME_PATTERN  pattern does?